# Is there a formal definition of "Proving theorem X without using theorem Y"?

Tags: logic, definition

In math textbooks and math classes, the author or professor sometimes says to prove a certain theorem without using another theorem. I understand what that means intuitively. But is there a formal definition of this notion somewhere, in some book or paper? Or, is this another one of those things that is "you know it when you see it"?

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to show that X does not imply Y?

Comment: You could say that if you write the proof as a sequent computation, the cut axiom $$\cfrac{\Gamma \vdash \Delta, A \qquad A, \Sigma \vdash \Pi} {\Gamma, \Sigma \vdash \Delta, \Pi} \quad (\mathit{Cut})$$ is not used with $A$ being the theorem that shouldn't be used.  However, you could eliminate the cut but still stay so close to a proof of $A$, that it still looks as "using $A$". Whether one considers the latter as using $A$ becomes subjective.

Comment: It ist just the same as saying you have to drive  from A to B without using highway Nr.... So it just says do not use there Nr.-- but try some other way. It does not need a "definition"

Comment: This is not quite the same, but you may be interested in Reverse Mathematics https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_mathematics , the study of what theorems are necessary in some sense to prove something

Comment: @TomKern Not theorems, axioms. If you can prove something and you have another theorem, you can always produce a new proof that "uses" that theorem, perhaps trivially. Also, if you have a proof of something, that uses a theorem, with some work you can remove the use of the theorem.

Comment: What if, instead of using Theorem Y, you just insert the proof of Theorem Y (potentially simplified to apply only to the conditions of Theorem X) into your proof of Theorem X? Does that count as "not using Theorem Y"? What if Theorem Y has two cases (say "easy" and "hard" case) and because Theorem X only uses the "easy" case, I don't even reproduce the whole proof of Y but only the proof of the "easy" case of Y? Etc. etc.

Comment: Or do we interpret it in the "legalese" sense - make a proof of Theorem X that cannot in the court of law count as derivative work of Theorem Y. Looks to me that this is more of *that* sort of question.

Comment: I'd say that if one does what @StinkingBishop describes above and adapts the proof of Y to the specific conditions and conclusions required by X, stripping away the unnecessary parts of Y, then you get a proof of X that does not use Y. The point is to "see directly" why X is true instead of seeing it as a consequence of the "opaque" theorem Y. In any case, these are very much informal notions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are both theorems of some formal system $\cal T$, then there is no meaningful way of saying "every proof of $X$ involves $Y$". If $Y$ is an *axiom* of $\cal T$, then it does make sense to say $X$ can be proved without using the axiom $Y$.