# What does it mean to say that to define X, you must first define Y?

Tags: definition, model-theory

This is analogous to my previous question on what it means to prove a theorem X without using theorem Y, here: [Is there a formal definition of "Proving theorem X without using theorem Y"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4513203/is-there-a-formal-definition-of-proving-theorem-x-without-using-theorem-y). But my current question is about definitions. Frequently in math textbooks, the authors state something like, "Before defining this notion, we must first define...". What does that even mean, rigorously? I mean, I understand the informal statement that, for example, you can't define a monoid without first defining what a binary operation is. But I don't know how to make that informal statement rigorous. Has anyone rigorously defined, given a base structure $M$, what it means to say that to define a constant $c$ or a function $f$ or a relation $R$, you must first define another constant and/or function and/or relation? Is that even possible? Or is this one of those intuitive and informal things where there is no formalization of it?

Comment: Do textbooks really frequently use the word "must" in that way? It seems unnecessary and possibly misleading (as it seems to imply there's only one right way to define any given mathematical concept).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, as has happened with some of your previous questions, you're looking for a formal notion where none exists; the language you're responding to is informal and motivational, and generally making a pedagogical rather than mathematical point.

That said, there are indeed meaningful notions of definability which are nontransitive. For example, see [this MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/426359/is-there-a-simple-instance-of-intransitivity-for-implicit-definability) for a proof of the intransitivity of a kind of **implicit definability** (with natural examples for first-order logic, and a sketch of a somewhat-artificial theorem for "tame" logics in general). And [this old question of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424584/are-there-quantifiers-that-require-multiple-steps-to-define) (building off of an MSE question of Greg Nisbet) points towards a likely intransitivity of a different type of definability.

My overall answer, then, is this: there are interesting precise notions of definability which are known to be, or are plausibly, "intransitive" and so support a nontrivial formal interpretation of "you have to define $X$ before you define $Y$." **However**, the original sort of language you're responding to should really be viewed as informal motivation rather than even a gesture towards any single formal notion.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could formalize it in the sense of fundamental axioms. In the sense that, from your subject's fundamental axioms, your subject is constructed entirely in terms of these. I.e, a given definition is either taken as fact in and of itself, necessarily not having a precursor, or a definition is predicated on axioms itself or another definition which if you follow through should eventually lead to some set of axioms.

I think also rigor is a misused word here. You could ostensibly prove and define everything in terms of axioms/previously proved things only. For example, you could certainly never define multiplication and just do addition. You technically wouldn't lose or gain any correctness (outside of the absurd lack of clarity this would introduce).

This is maybe getting off topic, but really I don't think there is necessarily  anything (other than perhaps common sense) stopping you from defining something in terms of operations that don't exist. A practical example of this would be writing a proof assuming you are able to prove a particularly difficult quality/step at a later date.

You could even argue you do this when you define an object implicitly, I suppose.

But to really make sure I answered your question, I think the rigor essentially boils down to the classic if statement, "If p, then q." Before defining p, you have no way to know the truth of the statement "If p, then q."